# Force Ant to substitue a substitution variable

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I use a software (Drops) based on ant script.

I try to dynamically generate the destination path of a file that I want to copy. To do this I execute a linux command line.

In my application, I have this properties :

- environment.props.environment_name=recette
- application.props.target.gmao=/opt/${environment.props.environment_name}/gmao-ws

I expected Ant to replace ${environment.props.environment_name} by its value at runtime. But it doesn't.

Here is the Ant script that I wrote :

```
<project xmlns:drops="antlib:com.arcadsoftware.mmk.anttasks" name="deployJar" basedir="." default="main">
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>
    <taskdef resource="com/dropssoftware/drops/ant/antlib.xml"/>
    <loadDropsContext/>

    <target name="main">
        <!-- get the value of the property "application.props.target.gmao" -->
        <propertycopy name="target.dir" from="application.props.target.gmao"/>
        <!-- I expect this to print target.dir=/opt/recette/gmao-ws but it print target.dir=/opt/${environment.props.environment_name}/gmao-ws -->
        <echoproperties />
        <!-- Supposed to copy from /opt/drops/storage/afile.jar to /opt/recette/gmao-ws but the property "target.dir" is wrong -->
        <exec executable="sudo">
            <arg value="/bin/cp"/>
            <arg value="${param.artifacts.root}/${param.jar.root}"/>
            <arg value="${target.dir}"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

With this input :

- param.env=gmao
- param.artifacts.root=/opt/drops/storage/

It is supposed to copy a file from the artifacts directory to the /opt/recette/gmao-ws directory. But Ant tried to copy it to /opt/${environment.props.environment_name}/gmao-ws.

I don't understand why Ant doesn't replace ${environment.props.environment_name} by its value.

Is it possible to force Ant to replace the substitution variable by its value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I find the answer to my question in ant document :
https://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html

> Normally property values can not be changed, once a property is set, most tasks will not allow its value to be modified.

In the case of the software that I use : Drops, it loaded the application properties BEFORE the environment properties.

So application.props.target.gmao is set BEFORE environment.props.environment_name and the ${environment.props.environment_name} cannot be replace.

The answer to my question is seems to be NO, it's not possible to force Ant to replace the substitution variable by its value.
It's done automatically if the variables are loaded in the good order.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely clear what you're trying to do. The [propertycopy](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertycopy.html) task is not part of normal Ant, coming from a 3rd party extension called ant-contrib

I suspect what you're trying to do can be done with normal property substitution. I have provided an example.

## Example

A simple example of how to pass in parameters to a build file by setting properties:

```
$ ant -Dparam.from=AAA -Dparam.to=BBB

build:
     [echo] 
     [echo]     sudo
     [echo]     /bin/cp
     [echo]     /opt/drops/storage/AAA
     [echo]     /opt/drops/storage/BBB
     [echo]
```

### build.xml

Note the 3 properties declared at the top? These are effectively the default values available for override.

```
<project name="demo" default="build">

  <property name="param.artifacts.root" value="/opt/drops/storage"/>
  <property name="param.from"           value="fromDir"/>
  <property name="param.to"             value="toDir"/>

  <target name="build">
    <echo>
    sudo
    /bin/cp
    ${param.artifacts.root}/${param.from}
    ${param.artifacts.root}/${param.to}
    </echo>
  </target>

</project>
```

Comment: I add more informations.
What I want to do is dynamically generate the path where I want to copy my file.
I use propertycopy to choose a path in the list of properties. This works fine.
My problem is that ${environment.props.environment_name} is not replaced by its value.

Comment: @YLombardi I don't understand your requirement. Nor is it clear to me why you need to use propertycopy, a task that is not supported by core ANT.

Comment: Propertycopy is not the problem, it work as expected.
My problem is with ant that doesn't replace the ${environment.props.environment_name} variable by its value.